# Still having trouble implementing the action Listener for a help button that opens a JavaDoc

Tags: java, android, html, oracle

I am having trouble calling the "How to Integrate with the Desktop Class" from another class, which is essentially a help button that when pressed calls the Desktop Class and displays my JavaDoc. Here is the code for the help button that I am using:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Gui extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JButton autoButton;
    private FlowLayout layout;
    public Gui() {
        super("Help");
        layout = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER);
        setLayout(layout);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
        setSize(300, 300);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        autoButton = new JButton("Help");
        add(autoButton);
        autoButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                DesktopDemo.onLaunchBrowser(e);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Gui().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And, here is the "How to Integrate with the Desktop Class" which I am using to open my JavaDoc. There are only a few minor changes I have included, mainly just changing some variables to 'static'. The original desktop demo is found at the bottom of the following Oracle Java Documentation page [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/desktop.html)
Here is my version:

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 1995, 2008, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 * are met:
 *
 *   - Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *
 *   - Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
 *     documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 *
 *   - Neither the name of Oracle or the names of its
 *     contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
 *     from this software without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS
 * IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
 * THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
 * PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED.  IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR
 * CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL,
 * EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
 * PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR
 * PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING
 * NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS
 * SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 */



/*
 * DesktopDemo.java
 *
 */

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class DesktopDemo extends JFrame {

    JButton btnLaunchApplication = new JButton("Launch Application");
    JButton btnLaunchBrowser = new JButton("Launch Browser");
    JButton btnLaunchEmail = new JButton();
    JRadioButton rbEdit = new JRadioButton("Edit");
    JRadioButton rbOpen = new JRadioButton("Open", true);
    JRadioButton rbPrint = new JRadioButton("Print");
    JTextField txtBrowserURI = new JTextField();
    JTextField txtMailTo = new JTextField();
    JTextField txtFile = new JTextField();
    ButtonGroup bgAppAction = new ButtonGroup();
    JLabel lblMailRecipient = new JLabel("E-mail:");
    JLabel lblBrowserUri = new JLabel("URI:");
    JLabel lblFile = new JLabel("File:");
    JButton btnFile = new JButton("...");
    JLabel emptyLabel = new JLabel(" ");
    JPanel conLeft = new JPanel();
    JPanel conCenter = new JPanel();
    JPanel conRight = new JPanel();
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    File file;


    private static Desktop desktop;
    private Desktop.Action action = Desktop.Action.OPEN;


    /**
     * Creates new form DesktopDemo
     */
    public DesktopDemo() {
        // init all gui components
        initComponents();
        // disable buttons that launch browser, email client,
        // disable buttons that open, edit, print files
        disableActions();
        // before any Desktop APIs are used, first check whether the API is
        // supported by this particular VM on this particular host
        if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
            desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
            // now enable buttons for actions that are supported.
            enableSupportedActions();
        }
        //loadFrameIcon();
        setResizable(false);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Use an appropriate Look and Feel */
        try {
            //UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
            //UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel");
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        /* Turn off metal's use of bold fonts */
        UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new DesktopDemo().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    /** Create and show components
     */
    private void initComponents() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("DesktopDemo");
        txtBrowserURI.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                onLaunchBrowser(null);
            }
        });

        btnLaunchBrowser.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

                onLaunchBrowser(evt);
            }
        });


        txtMailTo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                onLaunchMail(null);
            }
        });

        btnLaunchEmail.setText("Launch Mail");
        btnLaunchEmail.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                onLaunchMail(evt);
            }
        });


        txtFile.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                onLaunchDefaultApplication(null);
            }
        });

        rbOpen.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                onOpenAction(evt);
            }
        });


        rbEdit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                onEditAction(evt);
            }
        });


        rbPrint.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                onPrintAction(evt);
            }
        });

        btnLaunchApplication.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                onLaunchDefaultApplication(evt);
            }
        });

        btnFile.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                onChooseFile(evt);
            }
        });

        Container conFrame = this.getContentPane();

        bgAppAction.add(rbOpen);
        bgAppAction.add(rbEdit);
        bgAppAction.add(rbPrint);

        // Components layouting

        GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(conFrame);
        conFrame.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);
        layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);

        GroupLayout.SequentialGroup majorHGroup = layout.createSequentialGroup();

        // Horizontal group

        GroupLayout.ParallelGroup lblHGroup =
                layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING);
        lblHGroup.addComponent(lblBrowserUri, GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING);
        lblHGroup.addComponent(lblMailRecipient, GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING);
        lblHGroup.addComponent(lblFile, GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING);

        GroupLayout.ParallelGroup txtFieldsHGroup =
                layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING);
        txtFieldsHGroup.addComponent(txtMailTo);
        txtFieldsHGroup.addComponent(txtBrowserURI);
        GroupLayout.SequentialGroup rbHGroup = layout.createSequentialGroup();
        rbHGroup.addComponent(rbOpen);
        rbHGroup.addComponent(rbEdit);
        rbHGroup.addComponent(rbPrint);
        txtFieldsHGroup.addGroup(rbHGroup);
        GroupLayout.SequentialGroup fileHGroup = layout.createSequentialGroup();
        fileHGroup.addComponent(txtFile);
        fileHGroup.addComponent(btnFile);
        txtFieldsHGroup.addGroup(fileHGroup);

        GroupLayout.ParallelGroup btnHGroup =
                layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING);
        btnHGroup.addComponent(btnLaunchBrowser);
        btnHGroup.addComponent(btnLaunchEmail);
        btnHGroup.addComponent(btnLaunchApplication);

        majorHGroup.addGroup(lblHGroup);
        majorHGroup.addGroup(txtFieldsHGroup);
        majorHGroup.addGroup(btnHGroup);

        layout.setHorizontalGroup(majorHGroup);

        // Vertical group

        GroupLayout.SequentialGroup majorVGroup = layout.createSequentialGroup();

        GroupLayout.ParallelGroup uriVGroup =
                layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE);
        uriVGroup.addComponent(lblBrowserUri);
        uriVGroup.addComponent(txtBrowserURI);
        uriVGroup.addComponent(btnLaunchBrowser);

        GroupLayout.ParallelGroup mailVGroup =
                layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE);
        mailVGroup.addComponent(lblMailRecipient);
        mailVGroup.addComponent(txtMailTo);
        mailVGroup.addComponent(btnLaunchEmail);

        GroupLayout.ParallelGroup rbVGroup =
                layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE);
        rbVGroup.addComponent(rbOpen);
        rbVGroup.addComponent(rbEdit);
        rbVGroup.addComponent(rbPrint);

        GroupLayout.ParallelGroup fileVGroup =
                layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE);
        fileVGroup.addComponent(lblFile);
        fileVGroup.addComponent(btnLaunchApplication);
        fileVGroup.addComponent(txtFile);
        fileVGroup.addComponent(btnFile);

        majorVGroup.addGroup(uriVGroup);
        majorVGroup.addGroup(mailVGroup);
        majorVGroup.addGroup(rbVGroup);
        majorVGroup.addGroup(fileVGroup);

        layout.setVerticalGroup(majorVGroup);

        pack();
    }

    /**
     * Load the "desktop" icon into our frame window.
     */


    /*
     * Set the Desktop.Action to PRINT before invoking
     * the default application.
     */
    private void onPrintAction(ActionEvent evt) {
        action = Desktop.Action.PRINT;
    }

    /**
     * Set the Desktop.Action to EDIT before invoking
     * the default application.
     */
    private void onEditAction(ActionEvent evt) {
        action = Desktop.Action.EDIT;
    }

    /**
     * Set the Desktop.Action to OPEN before invoking
     * the default application.
     */
    private void onOpenAction(ActionEvent evt) {
        action = Desktop.Action.OPEN;
    }

    /**
     * Launch the default application associated with a specific
     * filename using the preset Desktop.Action.
     *
     */
    private void onLaunchDefaultApplication(ActionEvent evt) {
        String fileName = txtFile.getText();
        File file = new File(fileName);

        try {
            switch(action) {
                case OPEN:
                    desktop.open(file);
                    break;
                case EDIT:
                    desktop.edit(file);
                    break;
                case PRINT:
                    desktop.print(file);
                    break;
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            //ioe.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Cannot perform the given operation to the " + file + " file");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Launch the default email client using the "mailto"
     * protocol and the text supplied by the user.
     *
     */
    private void onLaunchMail(ActionEvent evt) {
        String mailTo = txtMailTo.getText();
        URI uriMailTo = null;
        try {
            if (mailTo.length() > 0) {
                uriMailTo = new URI("mailto", mailTo, null);
                desktop.mail(uriMailTo);
            } else {
                desktop.mail();
            }
        } catch(IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        } catch(URISyntaxException use) {
            use.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Launch the default browser with the text provided by the
     * user.
     *
     */
    public static void onLaunchBrowser(ActionEvent evt) {
         String urlStr = "file:///C:/Users/howhowhows/workspace/OPTICS_DROP_MENU/doc/index.html";
            URL url = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(urlStr);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            URI uri = null;
            try {
                uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        try {
            desktop.browse(uri);
        } catch(IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("The system cannot find the " + uri + " file specified");
            //ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void onChooseFile(ActionEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getSource() == btnFile) {
            int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(DesktopDemo.this);
            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                file = fc.getSelectedFile();
                txtFile.setText(file.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Enable actions that are supported on this host.
     * The actions are: open browser, open email client, and
     * open, edit, and print files using their associated application
     */

    private void enableSupportedActions() {
        if (desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE)) {
            txtBrowserURI.setEnabled(true);
            btnLaunchBrowser.setEnabled(true);
        }
        if (desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.MAIL)) {
            txtMailTo.setEnabled(true);
            btnLaunchEmail.setEnabled(true);
        }
        if (desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.OPEN)) {
            rbOpen.setEnabled(true);
        }
        if (desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.EDIT)) {
            rbEdit.setEnabled(true);
        }
        if (desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.PRINT)) {
            rbPrint.setEnabled(true);
        }
        if (rbEdit.isEnabled() || rbOpen.isEnabled() || rbPrint.isEnabled()) {
            txtFile.setEnabled(true);
            btnLaunchApplication.setEnabled(true);
            btnFile.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Disable all graphical components until we know
     * whether their functionality is supported.
     */
    private void disableActions() {
        txtBrowserURI.setEnabled(false);
        btnLaunchBrowser.setEnabled(false);

        txtMailTo.setEnabled(false);
        btnLaunchEmail.setEnabled(false);

        rbEdit.setEnabled(false);
        rbOpen.setEnabled(false);
        rbPrint.setEnabled(false);

        txtFile.setEnabled(false);
        btnLaunchApplication.setEnabled(false);
        btnFile.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

And, here is the error that I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at DesktopDemo.onLaunchBrowser(DesktopDemo.java:383)
    at Gui$1.actionPerformed(Gui.java:26)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

If anyone out there knows what I am doing wrong, and why I am getting a Null Pointer Exception, could you please post your proposed code and the changes etc.. Please be aware that I am quite new to java, so you may have to have some patience if I ask a stupid question. Thanks for reading this question, I look forward to seeing some feedback. Cheers, Ben.   c",)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NPE is because of the below reason

```
try {
            desktop.browse(uri);
        } catch(IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("The system cannot find the " + uri + " file specified");
            //ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
```

you are initializing desktop in DesktopDemo constructor but onLaunchBrowser() is a static method so desktop object is not instantiated!

Comment: Yeah, I understand that, so how do I get around that? If I change desktop back to non-static, it gives me an error?

Comment: Either remove the static keyword from your onLaunchBrowser() and create an instance for Desktop class and then call onLaunchBrowser() method or make sure that Desktop object is instantiated before using it!

Comment: Does anyone know how to instantiate the desktop object in my code, or how to create an instance for the Desktop class, I have no idea, I am new to java?

Comment: remove static variable from the method definition and create an instance in actionPerformed like this. new DesktopDemo().onLaunchBrowser(e);

Comment: Thanks heaps @Shriram works perfectly, I guess our Optical Fibre program will have the help button working when it gets sent to the international space station. Cheers, Ben. c",)